# Python 2.7/Kivy - Run a script clicking on a button

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am using Kivy for Python to create my first interface for a script.
The interface works but I have not understood how to run the script inside the `def sender(self)` clicking on the button "Go!" that I have created.

EDIT1: added in bold the solution offered by Qback.. the code is not running at the moment (indentation error on `self.button.bind` inside the `OutlookSend` class)

Any suggestion? Below my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import win32com.client as win32

class OutlookSend(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OutlookSend, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Insert the date (format: DD-MM-YYYY, 00:00 AM)'))
        self.date = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.date)
        self.button = Button(text='Go!')
        self.button.bind(on_release=self.sender)
        self.add_widget(self.button)

class OutlookSender(App):

    def build(self):
        return OutlookSend()

###HERE STARTS THE SCRIPT###

def sender(self):

    outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

    outbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5) 

    messages = outbox.Items.restrict("[SentOn] > '11/06/2017 9:00 AM'")

    for message in messages:
       # print message - use this to verify if the restrict works before launching the script
       NewMsg = message.Forward()
       NewMsg.Body = message.Body
       NewMsg.Subject = message.Subject
       NewMsg.To = "mail@mail.com"
       NewMsg.Send()

###HERE THE SCRIPT ENDS###

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OutlookSender().run()
```

Comment: You must be kidding with the indentation error :D just count the spaces(4 each indent) or tabs(1 each indent). Also, the content of the for loop (`for message in messages:`) isn't indented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after that:

```
self.button = Button(text='Go!')
```

add that:

```
self.button.bind(on_release=sender)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - sadly, it is not working. I receive an indentation error (but I am using the same indent of the rows above)

Comment: ohh, ok. Actually while sender definition is not inside any class it shouldn't recive self argument, and you shouldn't call it with self. prefix

Comment: Thank you: how may I solve the problem? I have to put {sender} inside a class?

Comment: Yeah, I think, that it would look better. But isn't it working right now?

Comment: Sadly, no. As I wrote before there is an indentation error.